# Batch Script - Get Last Login Data/Time of ANY User On Computer

Tags: batch-file

I'm needing to set up a batch script that shuts down a computer if nobody has logged into it within the past 7 days.

I'm seeing lots of examples for finding the last login date of a specific user account, but am unable to find anything for last login date of ANY user account. If possible, I'd like it to also filter out things like automated deployments (such as PDQ Deploy), and only look at the last time a user account fully logged in.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: For something to run without a user logged in, I'm pretty sure it needs to be a Windows service.

Comment: I'll be having this run as a scheduled task deployed via GPO.